# how to work with "process.stdin.on"?

Tags: node.js, stdin

I'm trying to understand process.stdin.

For example - I need to show array elements in console. And i should allow user choose which element will be shown.

I have code:

```
var arr = ['elem1','elem2','elem3','elem4','elem5'],
    lastIndx = arr.length-1;

showArrElem();

function showArrElem () {

  console.log('press number from 0 to ' + lastIndx +', or "q" to quit');

  process.stdin.on('readable', function (key) {
        var key = process.stdin.read();
        if (!process.stdin.isRaw) {
          process.stdin.setRawMode( true );
        } else {
          var i = String(key);
          if (i == 'q') {
            process.exit(0);
          } else {
            console.log('you press ' +i); // null
            console.log('e: ' +arr[i]);
            showArrElem();
          };
        };  
  });

};
```

Why the "i" is null when i type number a second time? How to use "process.stdin.on" correctly?

Comment: have you tried http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're attaching a `readable` listener on `process.stdin` after every input character, which is causing `process.stdin.read()` to be invoked more than one time for each character. `stream.Readable.read()`, which `process.stdin` is an instance of,  returns null if there's no data in the input buffer. To work around this, attach the listener once.

```
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.on('readable', function () {
  var key = String(process.stdin.read());
  showArrEl(key);
});

function showArrEl (key) {
  console.log(arr[key]);
}
```

Alternatively, you can attach a one-time listener using `process.stdin.once('readable', ...)`.

Comment: Thanks. But couple more questions - why the undefined appears if i run it and press nothing? And if I set rawMode to false - it doesn't work, why?

Comment: A `readable` event is emitted when data can be read from the stream. So you'll have to check for `null` in the call to `read()`. By default, `stdin` is in cooked mode, which means characters are buffered and sent to the program after a carriage return. To make your program work in non-raw mode (cooked), you can send an EOF (Ctrl + D) after typing a character to flush the buffer or hit ENTER and strip the new line from input.

Answer (score 3):

This is typically how I get input when using stdin (node.js) This is the ES5 version, I don't use ES6 yet.

```
function processThis(input) {
  console.log(input);  //your code goes here
} 

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");
_input = "";
process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
  _input += input;
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   processThis(_input);
});
```

hope this helps.

Comment: How to call the process.stdin.on("end", ) function programmatically or interactively. I am not able to able to end using node js v.6.X

Comment: Hi, how is the process.stdin.on('end') triggered? I am stuck in my console and cant proceed with running the rest of the code.

Comment: Hi all, Control + D will trigger the process.stdin.on('end') function.