# What is the ".on" in "process.stdin.on" for?

Tags: node.js, stdin

I was on the Node.js website and I had some example code from a friend containing "stdin".
I went searching what stdin was and I do know now. 
Although, on the website from Node.js, they use "**stdin.on**".

I cannot find ANYTHING about it. Maybe someone can fill me in?! :)

```
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
  var chunk = process.stdin.read();
  if (chunk !== null) {
    process.stdout.write(`data: ${chunk}`);
  }
});

process.stdin.on('end', () => {
  process.stdout.write('end');
});
```

I was hoping someone could explain this to me on a non-expert level.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams

Comment: @JohnSlegers, I'll read trough the webpage in a second,but it doesn't really answer my question. I have 'scanned' the page and I cannot find anything about the ".on" add-on. Is there something I am missing, or was it intended to give me some background information :).
Edit: Thanks for answering as quickly as you did

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to work with "process.stdin.on"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460324/how-to-work-with-process-stdin-on)

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski, I had that same option pop-up at the top of the screen. I checked that page out before I asked my question. Although I wasn't able to figure it out. Probably because I am new to programming. :) EDIT: Also I am specifically asking for the ".on". Which is not what the person from that question was asking. I tried to understand what the purpose of ".on" and ".once" etc. was

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The `process.stdin` property returns a `net.Socket` [Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream) connected to stdin. [^](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin)
>
> It extends from `stream.Duplex` which makes it both readable and writable. [^](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket)
>
> All streams are instances of [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter). [^](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream)

Now that we understand this, let's look what really is that you can find in `process.stdin`.

`.addListener(eventName, listener)` [^](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_addlistener_eventname_listener)

- alias for `.on(eventName, listener)`

`.on(eventName, listener)` [^](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener)

- adds the `listener` function to the end of the listeners array for the event named `eventName`

`.once(eventName, listener)` [^](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_once_eventname_listener)

- adds a one-time `listener` function for the event named `eventName`. The next time `eventName` is triggered, this `listener` is removed and then invoked.

`.off(eventName, listener)` [^](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_off_eventname_listener)

- removes the specified `listener` from the listener array for the event named `eventName`

`.removeListener(eventName, listener)` [^](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_eventname_listener)

- alias for `.off(eventName, listener)`

What this means is that you can attach "listeners" which execute actions in response to various events emitted by stdin.

For example, when user presses a key. It is similar to DOM events such as `onClick="myFunction()"` attribute, `object.onclick` or `jQuery.on('click')`.

Answer (score 3):

Been struggling with the same question myself recently and after a bit of digging I found that according to the [Node.Js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_events):

> The `process` object is an instance of `EventEmitter`

If you head over to the [EventEmitter documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener) you can find more about the API and the `on` functionality there:

> Adds the listener function to the end of the listeners array for the event named eventName. No checks are made to see if the listener has already been added. Multiple calls passing the same combination of eventName and listener will result in the listener being added, and called, multiple times.

In my case it was looking through the TypeScript definition file for Node that led me down that route, with the following API methods:

```
export class EventEmitter {
    addListener(event: string | symbol, listener: Function): this;
    // Here is it
    on(event: string | symbol, listener: Function): this;
    once(event: string | symbol, listener: Function): this;
    removeListener(event: string | symbol, listener: Function): this;
    removeAllListeners(event?: string | symbol): this;
    setMaxListeners(n: number): this;
    getMaxListeners(): number;
    listeners(event: string | symbol): Function[];
    emit(event: string | symbol, ...args: any[]): boolean;
    listenerCount(type: string | symbol): number;
    // Added in Node 6...
    prependListener(event: string | symbol, listener: Function): this;
    prependOnceListener(event: string | symbol, listener: Function): this;
    eventNames(): (string | symbol)[];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I had a couple things that stopped me from understanding what I wanted to know. As I am not English I didn't even know the exact translation of emit (which made it hard to understand). And also I had never used the word 'listener' whenever I was programming. After that, I read your post again, and the first part makes sense. The second part... I've no clue what's going on... Thanks anyway :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could save someone else having to go through the pain I did to find exactly where `on` is!

Comment: Yup, after reading the part with "on" and "once" I realized where it was for and after some experimenting... I got it working! :)
Edit: I simply don't like to use code I do not understand... :/

Comment: There is a slight misunderstanding and confusion with "where it was" and "what is it for".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this question needs yet another answer, but very simply `process.stdin.on();` is (as mentioned above) just a listener - it's listening for a 'data' event which is fired when a user hits 'enter' on the keyboard.  When `.on()` hears the event, you get to do something by supplying a callback.  Under the covers Node will pass the user input to your callback.

Here's a really simple example:

```
// Listen for the 'data' event, then call myCallback...
process.stdin.on('data', myCallback);

let myCallback = (userInput) => {
// In Node the userInput is a Buffer class instance, so .toString() it
// It also comes with a new line character, so let's trim it off         
let input = userInput.toString().trim();
// Now do whatever you want with the userInput...
};
```

Normally you'd also have written an emitter to fire the event you are listening for, something like:

```
myEmitter.emit('myEvent', 'The event happened!');
```

but you don't need to - in this case Node emits the event for you, as soon as you hit 'enter' on the keyboard.  All you do is listen for it with `.on()`, then do something in response.

Answer (score 0):

`.on()` is used to listen to an event. It's like listening a `click` event on an HTML button. Actually jQuery has the exact same usage in DOM event.